# C++ using booleans across multiple files

Tags: c++, global-variables

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "worldActions.h"
using namespace std;


bool worldEvents = false;


void worldReactions(bool world);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {

        if (worldAction == true)
        {
            worldEvents = true;
            worldReactions(worldEvents);
        }
        else
        {
            worldEvents = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

//1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "worldActions.h"
using namespace std;
bool worldAction;
```

//header

```
#ifndef worldActions_h
#define worldActions_h
bool worldAction = true;
#endif /* defined(__asdf_Story__worldActions__) */
```

When ever extern is used I get linking errors and when it's not I get redefinition errors. How can I fix this so I can use a global boolean?

Comment: What linking errors do you get?  You should have `bool worldAction = true` in the cpp file and have `extern bool worldAction` in the h file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently compiling a global `worldAction` into each file which includes your header.  If more than one file includes the header or (as in your source file) any other file defines a variable with the same name, you'll get linker errors.

To fix this, change your header to declare the variable only

```
#ifndef worldActions_h
#define worldActions_h
extern bool worldAction;
#endif /* defined(__Julian_Story__worldActions__) */
```

and define/initialise it in your source file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "worldActions.h"
using namespace std;
bool worldAction = true;
```

Comment: When I do that i get 2 errors which are stated like this  "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "worldReactions(bool)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Have you included `worldActions.h` in `main.cpp`?  You need to either do this or declare `extern bool worldAction;` in each file that references it.

Comment: here is part of the main where it uses the boolean             #include <iostream>
#include "worldActions.h"
using namespace std;


bool worldEvents = false;


void worldReactions(bool world);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    while (true)
    {
        
        if (worldAction == true)
        {
            worldEvents = true;
            worldReactions(worldEvents);
        }
        else
        {
            worldEvents = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: That error is telling you that there is no implementation of the `worldReactions` function

Answer (score 6):

You use `extern bool worldAction;` in the header and put the definition in the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

use keyword `extern`like `extern bool worldAction;` & put definition `bool worldAction = true` in .cpp file